# C++ overflowed buffer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having trouble with a buffer overflow with the char command in C++, as I am new to C++ coding. Here is my code. My issue is on the seventh line.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    char word[90];
    std::cout << "Type in your name to find out your gangster name!" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> word;
    std::cout << "Your gangster name is..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Da" << word << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

How do I allow the variable to consist of an unlimited amount of letters?

Comment: Why not change `char word[90]` to `std::string word`

Comment: `char` is not a "command".

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::string` and `std::getline` in this case

```
std::string word;
std::getline(std::cin, word);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Why do people even use char word? It seems insecure.

Comment: @AlexSummers: They don't. It is.

Comment: @AlexSummers If you dig down far enough, you'll find that most (all?) implementations of `std::string` use `char` arrays to store their information. The `std::string` just hides all the memory management behind the scenes. I've worked on projects which prohibit the use of dynamic memory allocation past initialization in order to limit memory segmentation, in that particular case `std::string` couldn't be used.